# Create small nodes graph with highlighted paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to recreate the following drawing with TikZ.

[image: Small graph]

I have explored many different options but encountered the following problems:

- Haven't figured out how to make small "point-like" nodes.
- I was able to highlight some paths in one color, but not two colors at the same time.

I'm not asking for a full creation of the drawing by one of the members, just a nudge in the right direction for the problems I have.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here's what I have so far.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}

    \path [draw, fill] (0,0) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (1,-1) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (2,0) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (3,-1) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (4,0) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (5,-1) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (6,0) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (7,0) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (8,1) circle (1pt);
    \path [draw, fill] (9,2) circle (1pt);

    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,-1) -- (2,0) -- (3,-1)  -- (4,0) -- (5,-1) -- (6,0) -- (7,0) -- (8,1) -- (9,2) -- cycle;

    \draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,-1) -- (2,0) -- (3,-1)  -- (9,2) -- (8,1) -- (7,0) -- (6,0) -- (5,-1) -- (4,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which leads to this: [image: First try!]

Problems:

- How do I label points that were drawn with \path ?
- The two colored paths' colors blend together.

Comment: Could you post the code you've got so far? It is easier to nudge if we can see exactly where to nudge *from*. For the second colour, you will need to draw the path a second time, I think. You could use e.g. `preaction` or `postaction` for this. For the points, `\path [draw, fill] (0,0) circle (.5pt);` or similar.

Comment: @cfr Edited the answer with a small code snippet using what you suggested. Don't know the "preaction" and "postaction" instructions, could you expand on that?

Comment: There's probably a better way. I can do it using `scope`s and `shift` but it is ridiculously fiddly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds}

\newcommand\Twocolor[4]{
\path 
  let 
  \p1=($ #1 - #2 $ ),
  \p2=#1,
  \p3=#2
  in 
  node[
    draw,
    outer sep=0pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum height=3pt,
    text width={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    rotate={atan((\y3-\y2)/(\x3-\x2))},
    anchor=west
  ] (mydouble) at #1 {};
  \draw[#3,line width=1pt] (mydouble.north west) -- (mydouble.north east); 
  \draw[#4,line width=1pt] (mydouble.south west) -- (mydouble.south east); 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={
    fill,
    circle,
    inner sep=2pt
  },
]
\node[mydot,label={left:$v_{0}$}] (v0) {};
\node[mydot,below right=of v0] (v1) {};
\node[mydot,above right=of v1] (v2) {};
\node[mydot,below right=of v2,label={below:$v_{i}$}] (v3) {};
\node[mydot,above right=of v3,label={right:$v_{i+1}$}] (v4) {};
\node[mydot,below right=of v4] (v5) {};
\node[mydot,above right=of v5] (v6) {};
\node[mydot,right=of v6] (v7) {};
\node[mydot,above right=of v7] (v8) {};
\node[mydot,above right=of v8,label={right:$v_{k}$}] (v9) {};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\Twocolor{(v0)}{(v1)}{red}{green}
\Twocolor{(v1)}{(v2)}{red}{green}
\Twocolor{(v2)}{(v3)}{red}{green}
\Twocolor{(v4)}{(v5)}{green}{red}
\Twocolor{(v5)}{(v6)}{green}{red}
\Twocolor{(v6)}{(v7)}{green}{red}
\Twocolor{(v7)}{(v8)}{green}{red}
\Twocolor{(v8)}{(v9)}{green}{red}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\draw[red,line width=1pt] 
  (v3) -- (v4);
\draw[green,line width=1pt] 
  (v0) to[out=45,in=135] (v4)
  (v3) to[out=-45,in=-20,looseness=1] (v9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The two-color lines are drawn using a command

```
\Twocolor{<start-coord>}{<end-coord>}{<upper color>}{<lower color>}
```

Comment: This looks absolutely spot-on! Thank you very much!